# Vim on WSL: synchronize system clipboard? (set clipboard^=unnamed)?

Tags: cut-copy-paste, microsoft-windows, os-clipboard, wsl

While using WSL/Bash for Windows I want to be able to use `y` `yy` `3y` and `p` the same way they always work in vim, but connecting to the system clipboard shared by all apps, not to vim's internal clipboard... I already have ditto to manage clipboard history.

It seems that Vim already has a built in option to synchronize the copy/paste buffer with the system clipboard... Yet the problem when running WSL is that you actually need to use `/mnt/c/Windows/System32/clip.exe` to access the clipboard... So even though I would like to be able to use:

```
set clipboard^=unnamed
```

It doesn't seem to have WSL support yet.

I understand the neovim does have this as an option, but I don't really want to experiment with neovim right now...

For now, the closest thing to a workaround that I've found is:

```
nnoremap <silent> <leader>y :call system('/mnt/c/Windows/System32/clip.exe', @0)<CR>
vnoremap <silent> <leader>y :call system('/mnt/c/Windows/System32/clip.exe', @0)<CR>
```

But this is a really horrible solution in my opinion... It makes copying a two-steps process...

Of course I can do some copy and paste with the mouse/shift+ins, yet I think there must be a way to get this synchronization to work properly in Vim.

Comment: Recommend this solution https://superuser.com/a/1439881/711405

Comment: For those using Neovim that found this question, see https://github.com/neovim/neovim/wiki/FAQ#how-to-use-the-windows-clipboard-from-wsl.

Answer (score 13):

I'm aware this is a very old question but I recently found a good solution. After much frustration, I came across these ways to access the windows system clipboard by copying and pasting.

By copying, with vim version >= 8.0.1394, as noted in another answer https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/15190

```
let s:clip = '/mnt/c/Windows/System32/clip.exe' 
if executable(s:clip)
    augroup WSLYank
        autocmd!
        autocmd TextYankPost * call system('echo '.shellescape(join(v:event.regcontents, "\<CR>")).' | '.s:clip)
    augroup END
end
```

Pasting, mapping to fake registry commands, i.e. "=p or "+p or whatever.

```
map <silent> "=p :r !powershell.exe -Command Get-Clipboard<CR>
map! <silent> <C-r>= :r !powershell.exe -Command Get-Clipboard<CR>

" I thought this will be better :)
noremap "+p :exe 'norm a'.system('/mnt/c/Windows/System32/WindowsPowerShell/v1.0/powershell.exe -Command Get-Clipboard')<CR>
```

Right-click pasting works, but is unsatisfying if you don't want to use the mouse

Comment: On WSL `vi` I have added `nnoremap <S-Insert> :r !powershell.exe -Command "& {Get-Clipboard}"<Enter>`

Comment: Thanks for the helpful answer! I was wondering if it would be possible to also use a fake register for the yank command. Something like `noremap "+y :exe 'norm a'.system('echo '.shellescape(join(v:event.regcontents, "\<CR>")).' | clip.exe')<CR>` (which doesn't work...)

Answer (score 6):

What about this?

```
if system('uname -r') =~ "Microsoft"
  augroup Yank
    autocmd!
    autocmd TextYankPost * :call system('clip.exe ',@")
  augroup END
endif
```

`uname` is a Linux terminal command which returns OS info, such that it will return `Linux` for WSL. Whereas with `-r` flag, the command returns release info of OS, thus it should include "Windows".

`TextYankPost` is a vim event (see `:h TextYankPost` in `vim`), which detect your text yank activity.

`clip.exe` is a Windows command prompt's command in WSL (see `CLIP /?` in command prompt) which copy `text` or return from a `command` into clipbord via `text | clip.exe` or `command | clip.exe`. Here the `clip.exe` is executed from vim by vim function `system`.

Comment: in Neovim one can use `has('wsl')` instead of `system('uname -r') =~ "Microsoft"`.

Answer (score 2):

I've made a PR for WSL support to [fakeclip](https://github.com/kana/vim-fakeclip) some time ago.

See [vimawesome](http://vimawesome.com/plugin/fakeclip) on how to install it; `help fakeclip` for usage.

Comment: Still maintained?