# Change where a register actually points (in this case, redirect "+" [sys clipboard], to an external program)

Tags: external-command, microsoft-windows, register

Setting up vim on WSL, and I want to be able to redirect the vim internal clipboard to the windows clipboard. This is possible if running an X server like XMing, but I don't want to do that.

I have 2 programs, clip and get-clipboard, that I can run from the shell to access the clipboard. But how might I go about faking things so that clipboard operations using the + register end up piping the text to/from those problems?

Not above compiling myself, although that's not ideal.

Comment: You can probably make use of the `TextYankPost` autocommands in recent Vims. How that needs to be done, depends on how to call your external programs clip or get-clipboard, check [this answer](https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/15190/71)