# Creating vimrc kills my plugin

Tags: vimrc, cut-copy-paste, plugin-system, os-clipboard, wsl

I have the following ~/.vim/filetype.vim:

```
augroup filetypedetect
  au BufRead,BufNewFile *?Script.sml let maplocalleader = "h" | source /home/gergely/HOL/tools/vim/hol.vim
  " recognise pre-munger files as latex source
  au BufRead,BufNewFile *.htex setlocal filetype=htex syntax=tex
  "Uncomment the line below to automatically load Unicode
  au BufRead,BufNewFile *?Script.sml source /home/gergely/HOL/tools/vim/holabs.vim
  "Uncomment the line below to fold proofs
  "au BufRead,BufNewFile *?Script.sml setlocal foldmethod=marker foldmarker=Proof,QED foldnestmax=1
augroup END
```

This is the [HOL vim plugin](https://github.com/HOL-Theorem-Prover/HOL/tree/develop/tools/vim) . I want to edit *Script.sml files.

Now, when I write a ~/.vimrc file with the tip of [this answer](https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/20231/33647) vim stops to read the plugin, which I recognise by the syntax highlighting stopped.

```
if system('uname -r') =~ "Microsoft"
  augroup Yank
    autocmd!
    autocmd TextYankPost * :call system('clip.exe ',@")
  augroup END
endif
```

I wanted to use that .vimrc to make it possible to copy to the clipboard in a Windows Terminal for a WSL Linux using ctrl-c.

How can I make the two coexist, the HOL vim plugin and this clipboard extension in vimrc?

Comment: I don’t have the reference off-hand, but when you dont have a vimrc you get the defualts vimrc (`:help defaults` I think). You can runtime it or copy over bits or what have you. The most important for you are probably `filetype plugin indent on` and `syntax enable`

Comment: [`:help defaults`](https://vimhelp.org/starting.txt.html#defaults.vim) is indeed the correct reference.